# How to handle dropped movement RPC packets in games?

Tags: networking, rpc

I'm wondering how I should handle packet loss of RPC packets in my game.
For example, if the client is moving forward, but starts to strafe left after a while, but the strafe RPC(MovingLeft) got dropped due to packet loss.
The server will still think that the player is moving forward, but the client prediction will make the player strafe left instantly after pressing down the 'A' key.

Should you let the Client override the servers authority for some amount of time back in the past? How will this affect server simulations, if the client is modifying the past states on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most games do this, they'll accept the commands locally and render them as if the server received them and then it's up to you the developer to decide how you want to resolve any differences.

This is the main cause of "rubberbanding" in games where the client renders the user moving left, but then the character model jumps back to where it "should" be according to the service.

Something else you can consider is rather than simply calling your server with a single action at a time, call your server with the most recent 3-5 actions w/ timestamps ie.

- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec] -> server received
- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec], Left [1 - 2 sec] -> dropped packet
- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec], Left [1 - 2 sec], Forward [2 - 3 sec] -> server received

Something else you should do is to continually update your server regardless of whether or not a "new" action was performed:

- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec]
- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec], Left [1 - 2 sec]
- Actions: Forward [0 - 1 sec], Left [1 - 3 sec]

Comment: Wouldn't sending duplicates of action updates, even when no new actions occur, result in a unnecessarily higher bandwidth rate?

Comment: Sure, but how much data is that really? You're just sending a handful of bytes over the network (plus whatever overhead HTTPS adds).